# Loading binary data from a file into a buffer in Python

Tags: python, buffer, python-c-api, pep3118, pybuffer

I have a set of 640x480 images. I’m converting these images to a binary file format via Matlab… Now, I need to load each of the binary files into a buffer in Python, and then read data from that buffer. Can anyone help me out with how I might do that, or suggest a link? –Thanks.

Comment: Are you saving it to a .mat file?

Comment: have a look at  io.BytesIO https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO

Comment: http://code.runnable.com/UqJdRnCIohYmAAGP/reading-binary-files-in-python-for-io

Comment: Can't you just treat the file as your buffer and readline one line from the file at a time and do your processing that way? Just asking because "640x480" doesn't necessarily translate to a specific buffer size. You could also just read the whole file with .`open("image_file.jpg", mode="rb").read()`

Comment: I have binary file. I want buffer my file because I gono send byte by byte with serial port and I think if I buffer the file, I can send bytes faster,am I right?

Comment: I mean does reading **file** byte by byte slower than reading **buffer** byte by byte?

Comment: @user3397145 depends on the size of the file and how you are doing the reads. Reading with a Py_buffer generally means Python reads the file into memory before populating the buffer you receive – several things affect how that performs: Python 2 vs 3 (file I/O was overhauled in Python 3); the infamous GIL state, and other concurrency gotchas; the files’ disposition on disk and/or memory… etc. Reading with the unbuffered POSIX descriptor API is generally pretty fast (as is using a `std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>` in C++-land); `mmap()` can be very fast but not in all circumstances… basically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the C-API, you are going to want to use a `Py_buffer` structure (which is not a Python object – it is unrelated to `PyObject*`-compatible structures in the C-API).

- Basic information is here: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html

If not using C, you will be interested in `memoryview` – the Python-level analog to `Py_buffer` – and the file I/O builtins and library module(s):

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files